# Can high load cause PHP to not be able to write to a textfile?

Tags: php, iis, logging, php-5.5

I have a PHP script which is under high load with multiple calls per second (originating from another computer). It's running on PHP 5.5.14 on an IIS server. Every request and response to the script is logged using

```
file_put_contents('log_2019-09-12.txt', $msg, FILE_APPEND);
```

Every request and response is also logged on the client computer, and there I see occasional PHP errors like this one:

```
PHP ERROR 2: file_put_contents(C:\\WWW\\project-x\\logs\\log_2019-09-11.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

These seem to happen about every ~140 minutes, usually there are 8 of them in a row and then things work for another ~140 minutes, handling several requests per second and logging successfully to the log file.

Could it be that PHP is usually writing to an in-memory file and then actually writes the contents to disk every ~140 minutes, and that's what's causing this error? If so, how can I circumvent it?

Comment: Could it be that the same file is still being written to when the second call comes in and tries to edit the same file?

Comment: This is most probably a race condition issue. Easier way is to store the logs on DB and let it handle that, otherwise I think you need to build some sort of queueing algorithm in order to sort this one out.

Comment: @NicoShultz That's one possibility, but I'm presuming PHP is clever enough to deal with those kinds of conflicts? Especially considering how many millions of websites run PHP and possibly use `file_put_contents`, Stackoverflow should be littered by these kinds of errors by now if it wouldn't handle concurrent access to file..?

Comment: @MagnusW yeah i would guess that too but it wouldn't suprise me that much if that is not the case :) maybe you could check what he is trying to write to the file and see if there is anything weird about the content? just add a try catch and dump $msg

Comment: Try and add the `LOCK_EX` argument when writing: `file_put_contents($file, $text, FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX)`. From the manual: _"the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time"_, I would use a logging library, like [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog), instead of writing my own. That lib supports all kinds of logging, like to file, database, email and more.

Comment: @MagnusW the `LOCK_EX` argument that Magnus Eriksson proposed will probably fix it

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Magnus Eriksson in the comments

Try and add the `LOCK_EX` argument when writing: `file_put_contents($file, $text, FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX)` From the manual: `the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time`

Answer (score -5):

You have no permission to write this.
mkdir($path, 0755, true)
Check to see if you have permissions as you write.

Comment: if he would have had no permission it would always fail

Comment: Permissions are not the problem, since it writes to the same file successfully the other 99.99% of the time.

Comment: I've come up with two solutions.The first is to lock the file while writing it, and the second is to create a temporary file that updates the main file.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). I'm flagging this post for deletion.